# 2 ifs with 2 different returns to a insert query

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code for submitting data from a form. It used to work fine till there was only the first 'if'. Now I have 2 multiple select list menus, with data going to 2 different columns through the same query.

After submitting the form, I get a message "The query was empty"

```
<html>

</head>
<body>
<?php
    $username="username";
    $password="password";
    $database="databasename";


    // Configuration Settings

    $momdate=$_POST["momdate"];
    $Committee=$_POST["Committee"];
    $Number=$_POST["Number"];
    $CommitteeName=$_POST["CommitteeName"];
    $momdate2=$_POST["momdate2"];
    $meeting_venue=$_POST["meeting_venue"];
    $member1=$_POST["member1"]; - multiple select option
    $member2=$_POST["member2"]; - multiple select option
    $momdate3=$_POST["momdate3"];
    $actiontakenpoints=$_POST["actiontakenpoints"];
    $items=$_POST["items"];
    $prepby=$_POST["prepby"];
    $approvedby=$_POST["approvedby"];

    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


    if ($_POST) {
        $member1_string = implode(', ', $_POST['member1']); 
    } elseif ($_POST) {
        $member2_string = implode(', ', $_POST['member2']); 
    } else
        $query = "INSERT INTO `mangeshk_ktweb`.`dgmcmom` (`momdate`, `Committee`, `Number`, `CommitteeName`, `momdate2`, `meeting_venue`, `member1`, `member1`, `momdate3`, `actiontakenpoints`, `items`, `prepby`, `approvedby`) VALUES ('$momdate', '$Committee', '$Number', '$CommitteeName', '$momdate', '$meeting_venue', '$member1', '$member2', '$momdate3', '$actiontakenpoints', '$items', '$prepby', '$approvedby')";

    mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (untested):

```
if (empty($_POST['member1']) {
    $member1 = '';
} else {
    $member1 = $_POST['member1'];
}
```

Then same thing for member 2.

Comment: Or using ternary `$member1 = empty($_POST['member1']) ? '' : $_POST['member1'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the If instead of else if, because member1 and member2 both have the values means "member2" in array format, you can try with the below code.

```
$member1_string = $member2_string = '';
if (!empty($_POST['member1'])) {
    $member1_string = implode(', ', $_POST['member1']); 
    } 
if (!empty($_POST['member2'])){
    $member2_string = implode(', ', $_POST['member2']); 
    }
```

Comment: Siva thanks. Tried your solution. This is the error I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/mangeshk/public_html/MOM_send_data22.php on line 45

Comment: Hi, '{' is missing in second if condition.now try

Comment: Sorry for the late response Siva, but it didnt work. The data does'nt enter. I get blank output for both

Comment: Please send your html form